# Date no detecta inmediatamente cambio de fecha desde SO

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, date

he hecho esta pequeña prueba con `typescript` y `nodejs`:

```
setInterval(() => {
      console.log(new Date());
}, 3000);
```

y mientras el `script` esta en ejecución cambio la fecha en el sistema (Windows 10), y el `script` tarda aproximadamente 1 min para reflejar el cambio de día.

**¿alguien que haya tenido esta experiencia podría decirme si este comportamiento es "normal"?**

y si este comportamiento es el mismo cuando se hace un cambio de día normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Estuve probando en mi PC, que tiene Windows 10 el código que te dejo a continuacion, puedes probarlo copiándolo, creando un .html y abriendolo con cualquier navegador. Cuando cambio la hora del sistema, el cambio se realiza de forma inmediata en el navegador.

```
<script>

setInterval(function() {
    window.fecha.innerHTML = new Date();
}, 1000);

</script>

<p id="fecha"></p>
```